# Filter on recordType values

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

We need two separate tabs based on the same standard object. As salesforce doesn't support my requirement using standard configuarion, have created simple VF page and defined a tab. But as both the standard and custom tab are based on the same standard object. I am unable to seperate the record types on these tabs. And when i say filter i dont mean the list views. Its the record type name options you get when you configure a record type on an object-which i have done,but i need only 2 values on one tab and other 2 values on 2nd tab

Eg: I have tab A and Tab B based on Account. and have 4 record types on Account = Internal-A,Internal-B,External- A  and External- B. 
Then when i am on tab A: it shall show only "Internal-A,Internal-B" and for Tab B: External- A  and External- B".

```
<apex:page sidebar="true" > 
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Account" subtitle="Home" />
    <apex:enhancedList height="500" id="lview" type="Account" />
</apex:page>
```

Comment: How did you create these tabs? Are they Visualforce pages? Web tabs? Tell us more.

Comment: And when you say "filter" could you simply use List Views and a single tab?

Comment: If you're able to create the tabs (not certain how you did it), you could presumably assign separate page layouts to each tab that only show records with the desired record type.

Comment: @sfdcfox  Sorry guys if the question was confusing. As salesforce doesn't support my requirement using standard configuarion, have created simple VF page and defined a tab. But as both the standard and custom tab are based on the same standard object. I am unable to seperate the record types on these tabs.  And when i say filter i dont mean the list views. Its the record type name options you get when you configure a record type on an object-which i have done,but i need only 2 values on one tab and other 2 values on 2nd tab.

Comment: Can you post the code for your VF page?

Comment: @JeremyNottingham:  this is the code have tried. I dont know VF, but Tried as i came across our requirement--but am just started to go through VF.    Now am not sure how shall i filter the record types--as all 4 are on the same object Account--only i want them to get seperated at the VF tab and standard tab?.                                          <apex:page sidebar="true" >

     <apex:sectionHeader title="Account" subtitle="Home" />
 <apex:enhancedList height="500" id="lview" type="Account"  />
</apex:page>

Comment: Added your code into the question for you. This VF page just duplicates the existing standard Tab, as you know. I don't believe there is any native way to pre-filter the `apex:enhancedlist` tag to only show some of the list views. I would recommend a custom page with an apex controller, but this is a lot more work.

Comment: if a custom page needs to be  created for this requirement--then could you pl just put pointers what kind of work it would be? as am unable to visualize which tag shall i call for the record type  and get a filter using some alternative(which alternative can i try out--am not getting any insight). I am assuming if i would have pointers--may be i can explore and try to put some workaround..Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there was a similar question posted [here](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000glQ2AAI) that had the following suggestion, which sounds like it meets your requirements:

> Here's how:
>
> 1. Make a view for each record type where the view's filter selects down only to that record type.
> 2. Make a Quick View Tab that points to each of your record type views.

The original requestor noted the following:

> It worked great but when I wanted to create another web tab for a
>   different view there´s a trick: in order to get the appropriate view
>   URL you have to go to the original tab, select the view and copy that
>   URL (do not copy the URL from the Web Tab´s view after selecting a
>   different view).

There is an idea [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006tr1) to support this functionality OOB. This idea also goes over how to create the custom tabs.

> First, navigate to the view you'd like to tab-ify by going to the
>   overview page and selecting that view.  In my case, I'll go to the
>   Cases tab and click on the Open Cases view, which is a view I created
>   that shows all the open cases in my org.
>
> Save the URL of this view; you'll need it later.  It will look
>   something like
>
> `https://na1.salesforce.com/500?fcf=00B300000031l4H`
>
> Now go to Setup->Customize->Create->Tabs.  Click the New button under
>   Web Tabs.  Set it to Full Page Width.  Set the Tab Type to URL, and
>   give it a label that makes sense (I called mine "Open Cases" but you
>   can call yours "Cases" if you intend to hide the normal case tab --
>   just make sure you don't end up with 2 tabs labelled "Cases").  Pick
>   any Tab Style -- it's going to redirect to the Case tab anyway so this
>   doesn't matter.
>
> On the next page of the wizard, enter the following in the Button or
>   Link URL:
>
> `javascript:parent.navigateToUrl('<your url here>');`
>
> Don't forget those single-quotes around the URL.  So in my example it
>   looks like this:
>
> `javascript:parent.navigateToUrl('https://na1.salesforce.com/500?fcf=00B300000031l4H');`
>
> And voila!  You now have a tab that navigates directly to your view.
>
> Bear in mind that a quick JavaScript navigation of this sort breaks
>   the Back button minorly -- if you click this tab and then hit the back
>   button, you'll get bounced right back to your view.  You have to click
>   the Back button twice in rapid succession to get back where you
>   started.  Consider yourself warned!

Comment: Thanks Jenny, for taking effort to reply.  I have though tried a different way and got the required record types filtered over my custom Tab, but now i am unable to navigate to the corresponding pagelayouts ,by selecting a particular record type.So i will check the details you have shared and see how this works out .